# How to Merge two same database without duplicate data (MS SQL 2008 R2)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am developing Simple ERP Application using Asp.net 4.0 with sql server 2008 r2.

I have install two place at same application.

1. 1st place godown (Purchase entry done here. Stock Added Here)
2. 2nd place Counter (Sales entry done here. Stock reduced Here)

at end of the day I need to merge these two database. (Need to get exact Stock (Purchase - Sales)

the remaining  tables will not be affected. I need to restore both machine at same records.
How to integrate it efficiently?

Comment: By "godown" you mean *warehouse* ? Anyway there's no "merging". You are performing inserts/updates based on *your* business requirements. You are updating *one* subsystem, sales, based on the data from *another* subsystem, the warehouse. These *don't* store the same data for the same items, don't follow the same rules and processes. You don't *merge* them, you update the second subsystem based on changes pulled from the first one. You can do so for each transaction, not just daily, if you design the system properly

Answer (score -2):

there is no in-built way of doing this in sql server.

you can write a console app, load it on task scheduler in windows and schedule it to run once everyday and does the work you needed it to do.

or you can write a complex stored procedure and schedule in sql server to run once a day.

Comment: This isn't an answer. At best it's a comment : "you have to write the code". The way it's packaged doesn't matter. It could be *any* type of application.

Comment: Besides, SQL Server *does* have replication. This question isn't about replication of data though. It also has Integration Services, which *is* used to update one database from another in a visual way. The *developer* still has to design the SSIS package though

Comment: I need to know about any methodology like SqlBulkCopy or anything else

Comment: @Hisanth no you don't. You are talking about steering wheel decorations when the question is "How do I drive a truck?". You need to understand your *requirements*, the *business problem* and how to solve it. If you want a visual tool, it's Integration Services. This won't implement your business requirements though. It can only make it easier to pull data from one spot and push it to another

Comment: and even if you have right, you do not give any actually solution to the question.

Comment: @Hisanth in fact, you may be breaking the law if you "merge" tables. In some countries warehouse and sales have to be kept separately for tax reasons. Accounting ledgers are separate in all countries.

Comment: @Hisanth as for SqlBulkCopy, that's just a wrapper for the `BULK INSERT` statement. It's like a Philips screwdriver - it's just a tool. How do you know you *need* such a statement? Yes, you can use it, just as you can an INSERT statement or an SSIS dataflow to insert data into a table. After that, you'll have to update other tables based on your requirements.